# Sort an associative array in PHP using usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort my associative array like this one:

```
[
  "key_a" => ["avg" => 2]
  "key_b" => ["avg" => 3]
  "key_c" => ["avg" => 0]
]
```

I'd like to sort it by average, so I should obtain something like this

```
[
  "key_b" => ["avg" => 3]
  "key_a" => ["avg" => 2]
  "key_c" => ["avg" => 0]
]
```

So I decided to use `usort` but it trasforms my key in number, how can I solve?

Here is my code:

```
usort($materials, function($a, $b) {
    if ( $a["avg"] == $b["avg"] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["avg"] < $b["avg"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Then if I print the array I obtain something like:

```
[
  "0" => ["avg" => 3]
  "1" => ["avg" => 2]
  "2" => ["avg" => 0]
]
```

Comment: Have you checked the page that compares the PHP [sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [the `uasort()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead:

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with, using a user-defined comparison function.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem using this function :)